Using tesseract from cli on Mac cannot find eng
I installed tesseract cli with brew.
When I do the following command
tesseract --list-langs

it tells me
List of available languages in "/opt/homebrew/share/tessdata/" (3):
eng
osd
snum

when I then do
tesseract fname.png >> "./fname.txt" -l /opt/homebrew/share/tessdata/eng

it tells me
read_params_file: Can't open /opt/homebrew/share/tessdata/eng
Error in findFileFormatStream: truncated file
Error during processing.

and the text inside the fname.txt is
Usage:
  tesseract --help | --help-extra | --version
  tesseract --list-langs
  tesseract imagename outputbase [options...] [configfile...]

OCR options:
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
NOTE: These options must occur before any configfile.

Single options:
  --help                Show this help message.
  --help-extra          Show extra help for advanced users.
  --version             Show version information.
  --list-langs          List available languages for tesseract engine.

when I try
tesseract fname.png >> "./fname.txt"  -l eng

I get the same end result.
What do I have to do to output the text into a text file, how do I make it find eng? Which I can't help but feel should be easily findable as it lists eng in its list of languages.

Try this:
tesseract fname.png fname -l eng

